# C# Lambda-Select with conditions

Tags: c#, lambda

I created a `Command`-class which has two important members.

```
public class Command
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CommandExecutedCallback Callback { get; set; }
    public delegate void CommandExecutedCallback(Command command);
}
```

I save multiple objects of this class in a `List<Command>`.

Another class `CommandProcessor` has a member function `GetCallbacks(string name)`.

I want to use a lambda expression to get an array of `CommandExecutedCallback`-delegates with the condition that the name matches.

I can get all Callbacks with: `return commandList.Select(t => t.Callback).ToArray()`.

How can i insert the condition to get only commands with the specified name?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Select` is for a projection. Use `Where` for filtering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to a add a `Where` condition:

```
return commandList.Where(t => t.Name == name).Select(t => t.Callback);
```

You should also avoid calling `ToArray` unless you really need to. Unless you're specifically passing this data to some other method that requires an array, copying all of the data with `ToArray` is probably an unnecessary (and rather expensive) operation.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

```
return commandList
    .Where(t => t.Name == "someName")
    .Select(t => t.Callback)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Also, this is what i was looking for. Thank you too :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the WHERE not the SELECT. With Select you tell what you wnat from the list, and with WHERE you filter the list to show.

```
return commandList.Where(t => t.Name == "VALUE").Select(t => t.Callback)
```

Comment: You dropped the `Select`, which is still necessary.

Comment: I changed it, but I think its more important if he understand the difference between both of them.