# How to write C# LINQ code to select based on condition

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking to convert a list of one type to another type by a conversion method but only selectively (if the conversion result is null or not). It is shown in code below.

```
private List<B> GetBList(List<A> aList)
{
    List<B> bList = new List<B>();
    foreach (A a in aList)
    {
        B b = GetB(a);
        if (b != null)
        {
            bList.Add(b);
        }
    }
    return bList;
}

private B GetB(A a)
{
    if (a != null)
    {
        return new B();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there a way to write it using LINQ something like below. The issue with below function is that it will always move the data even if the conversion result is null. Result has to be array (array of B) and the input has to be list (list of A).

```
private B[] GetBList(List<A> aList)
{
    return aList.Select(GetB)?.ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<A>();
}
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Where` is, ahem, where you want to start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Lambda-Select with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290665/c-sharp-lambda-select-with-conditions) There are hundreds of duplicates

Answer (score 6):

You can select with `Select(x => GetB(x))` which will return converted object. Then you should filter it with `Where(x => x != null)`. Then convert it to `array`.

Note that I have used `?` after `aList` as `aList?.Select` so it will handle case when `aList` object is `null`.

```
private B[] GetBList(List<A> aList)
{
    return aList?.Select(x => GetB(x)).Where(x => x != null).ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<B>();
}
```

**Edit** You can use `Select(GetB)` instead if `Select(x => GetB(x))` also.

```
private B[] GetBList(List<A> aList)
{
    return aList?.Select(GetB).Where(x => x != null).ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<B>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered many situation where I desired a function like that, hence I wrote my own extension method. In the meantime, I don't think I won anything by doing that and you do just fine with [Karan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62125762/11034016). On the one hand, you won't gain anything in performance and on the other hand, it only increases complexity and readability of your code.

But, it helped me a lot to get into LINQ expression, understand what's going on on behind and understand differences of IEnumerable, ICollection, etc.

For the sake of completeness and potential inspiration, I am sharing my code anyway:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectByCondition<TInput, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TInput> input, Func<TInput, TResult> selector, Func<TResult, bool> checker) {
    using var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        var selection = selector(enumerator.Current);
        if (checker(selection)) {
            yield return selection;
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, you could use it like that:

```
aList?.SelectByCondition(GetB, x => x != null).ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<B>();
```

If you happen to encounter your scenario with the null check many times, the following simplification might still be useful:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectIfNotNull<TInput, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TInput> input, Func<TInput, TResult> selector) {
    using var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        var selection = selector(enumerator.Current);
        if (selection != null) {
            yield return selection;
        }
    }
}
```

The actual call can then be simplified:

```
aList?.SelectIfNotNull(GetB).ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<B>();
```